# How to check whether an object is a result of has_one or has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I build a query dynamically, based on either a `has_one` or `has_many` relation. So, I can end up with either an object, or CollectionProxy. How can I test, based on this result, whether the query used the `has_one` or the `has_many` relation?

I thought of checking the type, but the CollectionProxy's type subclasses the related model's type.

This dynamic query involves calling an attribute on an object, which can be either a `has_one` or a `has_many` relation. Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :names

user = User.new
attr = 'profile' # or 'names'
user.send(attr) # I want to check whether this is a result of which of the two relations
```

Comment: `if @foo.is_a?(Foo)`

Comment: That's my problem, what should I replace `Foo` with?

Comment: The class in question.

Comment: I think you need to add some more information to your question regarding what you're actually trying to do with the "dynamic query"

Comment: You could also try `if @foo.is_a?(Array)` - the CollectionProxy class extends Array so this should return true for a collection.  This whole concept feels quite fragile though.

Comment: I've edited my answer with more details. I've tried with `Array` and it returns `false` for a result of a `has_many`.

Comment: What is your exact requirement(s)? You want to load all user with profile seperately?

Comment: @Rubyrider I want to check whether the result came from a `has_one` or from a `has_many` relation.

Comment: You wanted to get caller of the association. Let me check for best solution.

Comment: Not the caller, just from what type of association did the result came. Check my example, cannot explain better :)

Comment: When you get the results back, and it's a collection, what do you get for `@foo.class.name`?

Comment: if those are your only two options then i would write an if/else and deal with each one seperately, in a more deliberate way, rather than just `send` it to the object, then try to work out afterwards what just happened.

Comment: @MaxWilliams So you say the before `send`ing, I should check whether the `attr` I am about to call on the object describes either of the two relations?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I get `Name::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` back.

Comment: So you could do `if @foo.class.name =~ /CollectionProxy/`.  I still think this is a pretty horrible way of doing business though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Active Record's [reflection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html):

```
User.reflect_on_association(:profile)
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasOneReflection:0x007fd2b76705c0 ...>

User.reflect_on_association(:names)
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection:0x007fd2b767de78 ...>
```

Within a `case` statement:

```
klass = User
attr = :profile

case klass.reflect_on_association(attr)
when ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasOneReflection
  # ...
when ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection
  # ...
end

### OR by macro

case klass.reflect_on_association(attr).macro
when :belongs_to
  # ...
when :has_many
  # ...
when :has_one
  # ...
end
```

This works based on the association declaration in your model (`user.rb`), i.e. without accessing the database.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually check the type of the result. You just have to check if it's an ActiveRecord::Base or an ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.

Following your example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :names

user = User.new
attr = 'profile'
user.send(attr).is_a? ActiveRecord::Base # true
user.send(attr).is_a? ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy # false

attr = 'names'
user.send(attr).is_a? ActiveRecord::Base # false
user.send(attr).is_a? ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy # true
```

This was tested on a Rails 4.1.4 but the classes are the same since Rails 3, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `try` like this:

```
post.try(:owner)
```

this way a `has_one` relation will return the `owner` and `has_many` won't.

It some situations it may be inconclusive, but should suffice for most of them.

`owner` is just an example:

```
class Post
has_one :owner

class Owner
belongs_to :post

post = Post.create ...
post.try(:owner)
```

returns `owner` if class `Post` `has_one :owner`, and `nil` if class `Post` `has_many :owners`

**For your example:** `user.try(:profile)`

Comment: Seems that neither a result of a `has_one`, nor a result of a `has_many` responds to `:owner`. Can you give a short working example?

Comment: Oh, I understand. But unfortunately, I cannot rely on actual model names since the whole thing must be generic, without knowing about any specific model.